# c++ searching through vector using std::find

Tags: c++

I am trying to use `std::find` with custom vector objects.

Comment: You need to show your `operator==`.

Comment: Shouldn't it be it != vector.end() instead of userDetails.end()?

Comment: @juanchopanza edited my post. added my operator== implementation inside

Comment: You should use `std::find_if`.

Comment: I dont get the idea of a person containing a vector of person. What is the idea behind that?

Comment: @KitFisto this is only an example..

Comment: Just an observation but if you have to use `std::find` on a `std::vector` perhaps you've chosen the wrong collection type?

Comment: It's okay, because in third argument of find you are giving it a value you want to find in this vector. You had to overload == operator, because implementation of find requires it to compare elements of vector with your person(name,name).

Comment: That looks fine (except you shouldn't call your data member "`vector`", that is confusing. Can you post an SSCCE (see sscce.org)?

Comment: So why you think something is wrong? Now it looks alright.

Comment: @juanchopanza ok maybe I should draft an better example next time before I post. sorry for the confusion..

Answer (score 1):

I do not understand the if statement following the find

```
 it = std::find(vector.begin(),vector.end(),person(name,name));
 if (it !=userDetails.end()) {
       //found
 }
 else {
       //not found
 }
```

What does this mean?

```
it !=userDetails.end()
```

And I am sure that these ietrators do not belong to the same range.

Maybe you wanted to write

```
 if (it !=vector.end()) {
```

EDIT: As I see you have uodated your code. However in main

```
int main() {
   person personDetails;
   personDetails.findName();
}
```

you created a default initialized object data members of which (i.e. std::string objects) are empty. Also the vector itself is empty. So I do not understand what are you going to find?

Also I do not see what function or method is used to fill the vector.

It seems that as the tahit person you use is a person that has the name and profile

it = std::find(vector.begin(),vector.end(),person(name,name));

then you can not find anithing if records in the vector contain pairs of different name and profile.

Look your own comment

```
/*e.g now my vector contains
         john male
         mary female
         susan female
```

so you can not find record defined as person(name,name). The arguments should have different values.

Define the operator as

```
bool operator==(const person &lhs,const person &rhs) {
    return lhs.name == rhs.name && lhs.profile == rhs.profile;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can see, your code is correct.

Comment: ok. thanks. maybe I am just scaring myself that it's wrong. sorry

Answer (score 0):

Following may help:

```
class Person
{
public:
    Person(const std::string& name, const std::string& profile) :
        name(name),
        profile(profile)
    {}

    const std::string& getName() const { return name; }

private:
    std::string name;
    std::string profile;
};


class FindByName
{
public:
    explicit FindByName(const std::string& name) : name(name) {}

    bool operator () (const Person& person) const
    {
        return person.getName() == name;
    }
private:
    std::string name;
};


int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    std::vector<Person> persons = {
        {"john", "male"},
        {"mary", "female"},
        {"susan", "female"}
    };

    auto it = std::find_if(persons.begin(), persons.end(), FindByName("mary"));

    // ...

    return 0;
}
```